# Flutter - How to make a custom input field with custom prefix design?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to make a custom input field with  custom prefix design?e like the image below

[image: custom Input]

I tried a lot for it but I can't make the prefix part inside the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

**Add dependency for country code picker**

[image]

```
 Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 127,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30))),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                            child: TextFormField(
                                controller: _phoneNumberController,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    hintText: "Phone",
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: CustomColors.LightGrey,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w100)))),
                        VerticalDivider(
                          width: 0.2,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(30))),
                          child: CountryCodePicker(
                            initialSelection: 'IN',
                            hideMainText: false,
                            showFlag: false,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was able to achieve it via custom paint.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `prefixIcon` property of `InputDecorator` to display somethig.

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: SizedBox(
      width: 50,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          '+91',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

You could also use `prefix` property but the text will disappear if text field is not focused.

If you want to add line after the prefix you could replace `SizedBox` with `Container` instead. And use `border` property.

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    prefixIcon: Container(
      width: 50,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          right: BorderSide(
            color: Color(0xFF272727),
            width: 1,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          '+91',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```